# How to receive and store CURL username with PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I have the command:

```
 curl -k -u **username:password** --request POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":\"31\",\"test\":\"New York\"}" http://siteteste.com/receive.php
```

I want to get the server-side username and password with PHP.
I am using the POST method.

My PHP:

```
<?php
  // Only allow POST requests

    ***// I want the username and password here with PHP POST.***

   ***$user = $_POST[""]; //  Not working :(***

   if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) != 'POST') {
      throw new Exception('Only POST requests are allowed');
    }

    // Make sure Content-Type is application/json 
   $content_type = isset($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] : '';
    if (stripos($content_type, 'application/json') === false) {
     throw new Exception('Content-Type must be application/json');
     }

     // Read the input stream
      $body = file_get_contents("php://input");

     // Decode the JSON object
     $object = json_decode($body, true);

        // Throw an exception if decoding failed
           if (!is_array($object)) {
             throw new Exception('Failed to decode JSON object');
           }

         // Display the object
          $getit = $object['test'];

          print $getit;
```

How can I do it?

I try, but not working.

I search StackOverflow and others site, but not found informatio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your body is json-encoded.

You will get your data here:

```
$body = file_get_contents("php://input");

// Decode the JSON object
$object = json_decode($body, true);

var_dump($object); // <-- do this to view your data.
```

The [`-u`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-u) option you are using is used for authentication. For example for [http-authentication](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php).

In case you want to add data, you have to modify your `-d` parameter. For example, here i added a user:

`-d "{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":\"31\",\"test\":\"New York\",\"user\":\"test-user\"}"`

Or in the other case you really want the [http-authentication](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php)-data use:

- `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']`
- `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']`